# How to fix "end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init!" in Ubutu?

Tags: kernel, boot-repair

Exit code = 0x00000100

How can I fix this? I got it after changing my partitions. First Ubuntu was still working, but than I got a error when I started the system. I don't remember what it exactely whas, but I found a solutions for it on a forum. I had to type something in the terminal, types yes a few hunder time to a few hunderd questions, and after type reboot.
But...the system wasn't responding to the reboot command so I did a hardshutdown. Ever since then I have this message.

I saw at the internet that it could be that there was not enough space available but I checked it and that isn’t the case.

I don’t know what to do and I need to use my Ubuntu for my school.

Who can help me??

Here is the complete error message:

[complete error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3pHI.jpg)

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I'm allmost sure it is 20.04 LTS. Is there a way I can check it?

Comment: Find settings scroll to the bottom of the list and choose about

Comment: But if Ubuntu doesn't boot up I can't go to settings right?

Comment: But I'm 98% sure that it is 20.04 LTS